# keras change the parameters during training

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I have a customized layer to do a simple linear-transformation. like `x*w+b`. I want to change the `w and b` during the training, is that possible? For example, I want `w1` in the first iteration and `w2` in second iteration.(`w1` and `w2` defined by myself).

Comment: Have you tried to use a callback to access the parameters?

Comment: sy, I'm new to keras. I will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: Could you give me some hints about it? Thanks.

Comment: I guess it will not work, like this. Probably this helps:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8170

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can do it, but you need to do it in a smart way. Here is some code you can play with.

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import *
import numpy as np 

class MyDense( Layer ) :
    def __init__( self, units=64, use_bias=True, **kwargs ) :
        super(MyDense, self).__init__( **kwargs )
        self.units = units
        self.use_bias = use_bias
        return 
    def build( self, input_shape ) :
        input_dim = input_shape[-1]
        self.count = 0
        self.w1 = self.add_weight(shape=(input_dim, self.units), initializer='glorot_uniform', name='w1')
        self.w0 = self.add_weight(shape=(input_dim, self.units), initializer='glorot_uniform', name='w0')
        if self.use_bias:
            self.bias = self.add_weight(shape=(self.units,),initializer='glorot_uniform',name='bias' )
        else:
            self.bias = None
        self.input_spec = InputSpec(min_ndim=2, axes={-1: input_dim})
        self.built = True
        return
    def call( self, x ) :
        if self.count % 2 == 1 :
            c0, c1 = 0, 1
        else :
            c0, c1 = 1, 0
        w = c0 * self.w0 + c1 * self.w1
        self.count += 1
        output = K.dot( x, w )
        if self.use_bias:
            output = K.bias_add(output, self.bias, data_format='channels_last')
        return output
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        assert input_shape and len(input_shape) >= 2
        assert input_shape[-1]
        output_shape = list(input_shape)
        output_shape[-1] = self.units
        return tuple(output_shape)

# define a dummy model
x = Input(shape=(128,))
y = MyDense(10)(x)
y = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(y)
model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
print model.summary()

# get some dummy data
a = np.random.randn(100,128)
b = (np.random.randn(100,) > 0).astype('int32')

# compile and train
model.compile('adam', 'binary_crossentropy')
model.fit( a, b )
```

Note: the following code is equivalent to what we did above, but it will NOT work !!!

```
if self.count % 2 == 1 :
    w = self.w0
else :
    w = self.w1
```

Why? Because having `zero` gradients (the former implementation) for one variable is NOT equivalent to having `None` gradients (the later implementation).